# combine tblr table with itemize - fails

Tags: tables, itemize

In the following example I try to combine a tblr table with itemize. It however fails with:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{tblr} on input line 12 ended by \end{itemize}.
```

This is the code example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
% Style changes
\small\centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}  
% tabular
\begin{tblr}{width=0.9\textwidth, colspec={|X|X|X|}}
    \hline
header X &
header items (X) &   
header enums (X) \\
    \hline
    %
    This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is a long text.
        \item This is a long text.
        \item This is a long text.
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is a long text.
        \item This is a long text.
        \item This is a long text.
    \end{enumerate}
    \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularray,varwidth,enumitem}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}
        % Style changes
        \small\centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}  
        % tabular
        \begin{tblr}{width=0.9\textwidth, colspec={|X|X|X|}}
            \hline
            header X &
            header items (X) &   
            header enums (X) \\
            \hline
            %
            This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.
            &
        \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,leftmargin=8pt]
                \item This is a long text.
                \item This is a long text.
                \item This is a long text. 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{varwidth}
            &
        \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
            \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,leftmargin=12pt]
                \item This is a long text.
                \item This is a long text.
                \item This is a long text.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{varwidth}
            \\ \hline
        \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]